# How can fetch data from one table but using multiple tables in the WHERE clause ( Yii2 )

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm trying to execute a query from the artisant controller, which its table doesn't have a direct relationship with the other table ( metier ) that is present in the where clause.

As you can see in the picture I have a table called `Artisans` which is joined to Rel-`artisan_metiers` this last one in joined to `Metier`, the problem I have is that I'm trying to displaying data from `artisant` table with joining the tables and also where `metier.libelle ="Plombier"`!

Where I execute the query I get the:

> Unknown column 'metier.libelle' in 'where clause'

anyone can help?

My action function in the artisant controller

```
public function actionHoome()
{
    $plom = "Plombier";
    $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('art.CIN')
        ->from('artisant as art', 'metier as met', 'rel_artisan_metiers as rel_met')
        ->where(['metier.libelle' => $plom, 'metier.id_metier' => 'rel_met.id_metier'
            , 'art.CIN' => 'rel_met.Artisant_CIN'])
        ->all();
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `'met.id_metier'` instead of `'metier.id_metier'` in `where()`.

Comment: the picture you added is also looking for the actual code? and you should change to `met.libelle`

Comment: @rob006   I've already tried it, it didn't worked

Comment: then check the column name and table names.

Comment: Your `from()` syntax is also incorrect - ti should be `->from(['artisant as art', 'metier as met', 'rel_artisan_metiers as rel_met'])`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam everytihng is written correctly already tested in phpmyadmin and it works fine

Comment: @rob006 I'll try it now

Answer (score 0):

> When the tables are specified as an array, you may also use the array keys as the table aliases (if a table does not need alias, do not use a string key).

Try:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('art.CIN')
        ->from(['art' => 'artisant', 'met' => 'metier', 'rel_met'=>'rel_artisan_metiers'])
```

Comment: It return an empty array I don't know why.